Registers an unload listener - Cloudflare - Lighthouse

Hello,
I am working on optimizing a website and use Cloudflare to improve its performance and security. Recently, when conducting a Lighthouse audit to evaluate the website's performance, I encountered a warning stating "Registers an unload listener."
From what I understand, this suggests that my website is utilizing the unload or beforeunload events in JavaScript, which can potentially slow down the browser and negatively impact user experience. I am aware that using these event listeners is discouraged as they can delay page unloading and lead to performance issues.
I would like to know if anyone else has encountered this issue while using Cloudflare and how it can be resolved efficiently. Is this a common problem related to how Cloudflare manages scripts, or is it a misconfiguration on my part?

If you know other services which like cloudflare , pls share it .thank you a lot

Try turning off rocket loader temporarily and running the test again.  The nature of cloudflare can make it hard to trace the actual source of any bug.  It may be being thrown by a different script.

Thank you, let me check
